# passing variables within variable array to calculate fields PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, switch-statement

Alright, I may be making this a bit too complicated for myself, but I am really trying to figure this out, and I am  stuck on how to make it work.  This is for a wordpress site

So the process I am trying to accomplish is this:

1. Determine client level to determine which price point the client will have.
   Options: High, low, medium
2. based on client level, select the appropriate product multiplier to use in my calculations
   options: p_high, p_medium, or P_low
3. Run an equation that calculates the final price depending on the multiplier type selected.
4. If client level is not high, the price will display a was/ now price point, so both the p_high, and p_low values will have to be used.

I have tried creating a function that sets an array  to run in a foreach loop to calculate the price1, and price2. But although I haven't tested it yet, I am pretty sure this is not going accomplish the goal I am seeking.

I'm going assume that I may be able to increment the variable name to create a price1 and price 2 variable, but I'm not entirely sure the best way to do that, or if its the right solution. If anyone could help me out, that would be great.

Note: The switch statement does include variables that were present with a previously defined associative array. The echo statement present will be replaced with the function once i figure out how to pass the variables properly.

```
function get_client_lvl ()
{$user_id = get_current_user_id();

If ($user_id == 0)
  {return "high";}
Else
  {get_user_meta($user_id, wpcf-client-lvl, true); }
}

$client_lvl=get_client_lvl();

function display_right_price($client_lvl, $multiplier)
{If ($client_lvl == "high")
  {echo "\${$price1}";}

else {
echo "WAS:\${$price1}<br/>";
echo "Now: \${$price2}";
}}

$p_high= 2; //get_post_meta($post_id,$key
$p_med= 1.5;
$p_low =1.1;
$cogs= 10;
$img_count =3;
$img_cost= 10;
$area= 40;
$m_type=  'Area';


if ($client_lvl == 'med')
{$prices=array($p_high, $p_med);}

elseif ($client_lvl == 'low')
{$prices=array($p_high, $p_low);}
else
{$prices=array($p_high);}

    Foreach($prices as $multiplier)
    {
switch ($m_type) {

     case 'Area':
         $price= $multiplier * $area;
            echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";/>";  //This will be replaced with display_right_price() function once the price variables are established
         break;

     case 'Image':

         $price= $multiplier * $img_count *$cogs;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";/>";  //This will be replaced with display_right_price() function once the price variables are established
         break;

     case 'Commission':

         $price= $multiplier + $cogs;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";/>";  //This will be replaced with display_right_price() function once the price variables are established
         break;

     case 'Flat':

         $price= $multiplier;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>"; />";  //This will be replaced with display_right_price() function once the price variables are established
         break;

     case 'Commission+Image':

         $price= $multiplier + ($img_cost*$img_count);
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";/>";  //This will be replaced with display_right_price() function once the price variables are established
         break;

     case 'Price':

         $price= $multiplier * $cogs;
         echo "The {$lvl} price is \${$price}<br/>";/>";  //This will be replaced with display_right_price() function once the price variables are established
         break;
}}
```

EDIT: I figured it out (Now just need to figure out how to pull the variables dynamically from two different post types:

```
function get_client_lvl ()
{$user_id = get_current_user_id();
If ($user_id == 0)
{return 'high';}
Else
{get_user_meta($user_id, wpcf-client-lvl, true); }
}

//$client_lvl=get_client_lvl();


$postid = get_the_ID();
$client_lvl='high';





function display_right_price($client_lvl)
{
$p_high= 3.2; //get_post_meta($post_id,$key)
$p_med= 1.3;
$p_low =1.1;
$cogs= 11.53;
$img_count =3;
$img_cost= 10;
$area= 40;
$m_type= 'Price';
$price=array();

if ($client_lvl == 'med')
{$prices=array('high'=>$p_high,'med'=> $p_med);}

elseif ($client_lvl == 'low')
{$prices=array('high'=>$p_high,'low'=> $p_low);}
else
{$prices=array('high'=>$p_high);}

    Foreach($prices as $multiplier)
    {
switch ($m_type) {

     case 'Area':
         $total[]= $multiplier * $area;
                       break;

     case 'Image':

         $total[]= $multiplier * $img_count *$cogs;

         break;

     case 'Commission':

         $total[]= $multiplier + $cogs;

         break;

     case 'Flat':

         $total[]= $multiplier;

         break;

     case 'Commission+Image':

         $total[]= $multiplier + ($img_cost*$img_count);

         break;

     case 'Price':

         $total[]= $multiplier * $cogs;

         break;
}}
$p1=number_format($total[0],2,'.',',');
If ($client_lvl == "high")
{

echo "\${$p1}";
}
else {
$p2=number_format($total[1],2,'.',',');
echo "WAS: \${$p1}<br/>";
echo "NOW: \${$p2}";
}}

display_right_price($client_lvl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to look into is [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Using "global" allows variables set outside the function to be visible within. For example:

```
function display_right_price($client_lvl, $multiplier) {

    // allow variables $p_high, $p_med, $p_low to be visible inside the function
    global $p_high, $p_med, $p_low;

    // ...

}
```

But maybe, to simplify things, you would pass $client_lvl and the product ID to your display_right_price() function, then perform all the calculations and print the prices from inside the function?

Comment: Hmmm, I'll play with that idea